# Can an std::vector<float> resize itself to a smaller size?

Tags: c++

```
SharedConsumableRotatingBuffer(std::optional<size_t> maxBufferSize_) {
    if (maxBufferSize_.has_value()) {
        ALOGV(TAG, "SharedConsumableRotatingBuffer resizing buffer to %zu", maxBufferSize_.value());
        buffer.resize(maxBufferSize_.value());
        ALOGV(TAG, "SharedConsumableRotatingBuffer buffer size: %zu", buffer.size());
    }
```

output:

```
V/playbackProgressPercentage( 4910): SharedConsumableRotatingBuffer resizing buffer to 17280000
V/playbackProgressPercentage( 4910): SharedConsumableRotatingBuffer buffer size: 17280000
```

I don't even insert elements using `push_back` or anything, I just do `buffer.data()` and memcpy elements inside of it.

However, I always check the boundaries before doing this. Well, turns out that doing `buffer.size()` at a later time gives me `3840000`, not the `17280000` from before.

So is it possible that `std::vector` shrinks itself for no reason?

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: If you want to know the allocated size, you should use `capacity()`. `size()` will only return the current number of elements, not how big the internal storage is.

Comment: Without a [mcve] we have to guess what's changing the size.  Probably UB and overwriting the `std::vector` control block.

Comment: `"I always check the boundaries before doing this"` - *Famous last words.* Please use `std::copy` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can an `std::vector<float>` resize itself to a smaller size?

Yes. If you provide a smaller argument than the current `size` of the vector to `resize`, then the `size` of the vector will be set to that smaller value i.e. elements will be removed.

<sub>Sidenote: that the `capacity` will remain unaffected by `resize` unless the size grows beyond the previous `capacity`.</sub>

> So is it possible that std::vector shrinks itself for no reason?

It doesn't shrink "for no reason". The `size` changes if you remove elements.

Comment: Also note that `std::vector` has [`shrink_to_fit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) to reduce the current `capacity` to match the current `size` if it is smaller.